# How to list ID column from one table and then make a list of names from another column based on those IDs LINQ?

Tags: linq

Ok, so the heading is not the best ever written, but here is the problem:
let's say I have three tables, for example "Services", "Clients" and "SomeTable" that stores IDs from both of the first two tables. Services table has two columns: "ServiceID" and "Name". 
Now what I'm trying to do is to select all the "ServiceIDs" from "SomeTable" where "ClientID" is 10 and then after I get that list, I need the names of all those selected services from table "Services".
I hope you understand what I'm trying to manage here, I'll be more specific if needed.
Thank you.

Comment: Please, be more specific on following topics: what data access technology you're using? Query will depend heavily on this... Is it Entity Framework? And, if so, your table "SomeTable" has columns ClientID, ServiceID? Those columns are foreign keys? Are there navigation properties in generated models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result=sometable
  .Where(st=>st.ClientID==10)
  .Join(services,a=>a.ServiceID,b=>b.ServiceId,(st,s) new {st=st,s=s})
  .Select(x=>x.s.Name);
```

Comment: if `sometable` and `services` are IEnumerables, then it works as is, if you are using LINQ to EF, where `db` is your datacontext, then substitute `db.sometable` and `db.services`.  Of course, if you are using EF, then Services and Clients should have navigatable properties to each other via sometable and the query is even more simple.  `var result=clients.Where(c=>c.ClientID==10).Select(c=>c.Services.Name);`